# How to produce a PS1 prompt in bash or ksh93 similar to tcsh

Tags: bash, ksh, prompt, tcsh

In tcsh, I have the default:

```
prompt  [%m:%c3] %n%#
```

which gives prompts like:

```
[woehler:hacking/c/hello] ajcarr%
```

and

```
[woehler:~] ajcarr%
```

In other words, the current directory and up to the next two above it in the path.

In ksh93 or bash, the substitution of `$HOME` by `~` is easy, as is extracting the name of just the current directory, but I have yet to find a way of replicating the `%c3` behaviour of tcsh. At present in ksh93 I have:

```
[ajcarr@Woehler] hello $
```

and

```
[ajcarr@Woehler] ~ $
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

In **`ksh93`**:

```
PS1='${PWD#${PWD%?/*/*/*}?/} \$ '
share/doc/libnl-3-dev $ _

PS1='[${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD#${PWD%?/*/*/*}?/}] $USER% '
[host:share/doc/libnl-3-dev] user% _
```

If you want it to also replace `$HOME` with `~`, something nastier is needed:

```
PS1='$(d=${PWD/#$HOME/"~"};printf %s "${d#${d%?/*/*/*}?/}") $ '
~/w/maemo $ cd sb2-pathmaps
w/maemo/sb2-pathmaps $ _

PS1='$(d=${PWD/#$HOME/"~"};printf %s "[${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${d#${d%?/*/*/*}?/}]") $USER% '
[host:w/maemo/sb2-pathmaps] user% _
```

---

All this should also work in **`bash`**, though `bash` has its own prompt escapes (eg. `\h` for `${HOSTNAME%%.*}`) and path shortening mechanism (with `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`).

Also, the nastier variant will be really nasty, because `bash`, unlike `ksh93`, will `fork()` a separate process for each `$(...; printf ...)` command substitution, even if it contains only builtins. This also holds true for `pdksh` derived shells, like `mksh`.

---

**`zsh`** has prompt escapes quite similar but not identical to `tcsh`:

```
zsh$ PS1='[%m:%3c] %n%# '
[host:share/doc/libnl-3-dev] user% _
```

---

Note:

The `$HOSTNAME` variable is not set by default in `ksh93`; instead of it you could use the `uname` builtin (after enabling it with `PATH=/opt/ast/bin:$PATH`; the `/opt/ast/bin` path doesn't need to exist):

```
PS1='$(d=${PWD/#$HOME/"~"};h=$(uname -n); printf %s "[${h%%.*}:${d#${d%?/*/*/*}?/}]") $USER% '
```

Unlike the `\h` escape in bash or `%m` escape in `zsh` or `tcsh` this *will* track the hostname changes.

Answer (score 6):

For bash, you could achieve *similar* results by setting the [`PROMPT_DIRTRIM` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables):

```
$ PS1='[\u@\h] \w\$ '
[schaller@r2d2] ~$ pwd
/home/schaller
[schaller@r2d2] ~$ PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
[schaller@r2d2] ~$ cd /home/schaller/tmp/513924/another/directory/here
[schaller@r2d2] ~/.../another/directory/here$
```